# Vaadin with azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, vaadin

I'm trying to use vaadin with azure AD to login
but I'm facing problems
first problem when I use the azure part of code for spring boot
I can't access my pages any more .. I got sever error or lost connection
only works azure part of code.
second problem
my localhost should open my home page but it opens directly login with azure and that is something I don't want to[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXluP.png)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 2):

I have my Vaadin app authenticating with Azure AD.

I followed this tutorial as a starter and tweaked where I needed to:
[Securing-your-app-with-spring-security](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security)

I only allow authentication via Azure to my app, but I do have some rest api's that are secured via azure jwt tokens.  To make that work, I ended up having 2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's defined with one of them specifically targeting my rest api url.  You may need to do something similar, but single out your home page and permit all to access it.

Comment: This link is now dead. If you could describe the info it used to contain in your answer, that would be excellent.